# Ubuntu server unattended upgrades and file mods

Tags: ubuntu

I've always been wondering a thing and never have set up this Ubuntu server feature because of this:

What happens if during the process of installing one unattended upgrade, the system needs to modify a file?

Comment: What are you wondering? Upgrading is more or less the process of modifying files?

Comment: Why wouldn't files need to be modified during an upgrade?

Comment: I think I explained it wrongly: when I mean "modify" a file, I mean a file modified by me that is core. I know that most of the programs have a mechanism to load user-mods so original files are left untouched so there won't be conflicts during updates. But I was wondering what may happen with automatic updates under this scenario.